# JavaScript calling function is not working

Tags: javascript

This is my piece of code and it is not working in the expected way. Can give me any idea what i have wrong

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="f(x, y, z)"/>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = prompt("Enter the number",""); 
var y = prompt("Enter the number","");
var z = prompt("Enter the number","");

function f(x, y, z)
{
    // first, check that the right # of arguments were passed.
    if (f.arguments.length != 3) {
        alert("function f called with " + f.arguments.length +
              "arguments, but it expects 3 arguments.");
        return null;
    }


}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: In the future, you should say what the problem is. What did you expect and what is happening.

Comment: Hi, at the first, i am checking the arguments that was passed is matching the 3 arguments or not. But, still, it is not working.. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be checking `arguments.length`, not `f.arguments.length`

Edit:
@TheMobileMushroom also pointed out that arguments length will be 3 even if the args are empty strings. You can change it to

```
if (!x || !y || !z)
```

Don't use `arguments.length`

Comment: Hi dude, I am still facing the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: What is the problem? Is the function being called? What are the values of x, y and z?

Comment: I am getting the value from the user through 'prompt'. Please see my code. For the function f(), i am getting the values from user.

Comment: I mean what behavior are you actually seeing? What apart of it is not working? Are you even getting into the function call?

Comment: I am expecting the alert box when i am missing to give 3 arguments. But, I am not getting any alert when i dont enter exactly 3 arguments.

Answer (score 3):

the function you are calling will always have 3 arguments. maybe you want to check if the arguments are not empty?

```
if (x=='' || y=='' || z==''){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the script tag before the form tag, so the x,y and z will be declared before.